# AWS CloudWatch - 100% CPU Utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, cpu, cpu-usage

I have an AWS M4.Large EC2 instance running a Magento e-commerce site that is experiencing consistent max CPU usage spikes at a regular interval: 10 minutes at 100% CPU, followed by 20 minutes at 40-50% CPU. I've included a screenshot below. I am trying to identify the cause of these routine spikes, but am not sure how to target the cause(s). I would assume an automated task is at play here, due to the regularity of these spikes. Any advice and suggestions would be extremely appreciated!

[CloudWatch Monitoring Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHNc5.png)

I am hoping to keep our instance type as an M4.Large, but if it requires an increase then I will bump it up. Unfortunately, I do not think that AWS Auto Scaling will be a viable option this web application.

Thank you! Suggestions are very much appreciated!

---

EDIT:
While looking at the Network monitors, it seems that high traffic correlates *exactly* to the CPU usage.

[Network Activity Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N52vo.png)

Comment: Have you looked at something like TOP and actively monitored the processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled the access logs if yes then you can easily figure it out whether  the requests are coming from your automation module or not.

**How to differentiate original request from automation requests**
 You can add some extra query parameter to the url,  Now you can start tracing all the requests generated by your automation module during that time.